# Export table to EPS figure without line breaks

Tags: export, list-manipulation, eps-format

I produce a 16x16 table of arrows as follows:

```
fun[n_, k_] :=  With[{t = Tuples[{0, 1}, n],  r = {0 -> "\[UpArrow]", 1 -> "\[DownArrow]"}},  Column[Row[#, "  "] & /@ Partition[Row /@ (t /. r), k]]]
fig = fun[nSpins, 16]
```

I then wish to export this to EPS; I do

```
Export["test.eps", fig]
```

However, in the resulting EPS figure there are line breaks, i.e. the 16 elements of each row are not actually all in one row. How can I force the figure to be a 16x16 table, without line breaks?

Comment: try `ClearAll[fun2];
fun2[n_, k_] := 
 With[{t = Tuples[{0, 1}, n], 
   r = {0 -> "\[UpArrow]", 1 -> "\[DownArrow]"}}, 
  Column[Style[Row[#, "  "], LineBreakWithin -> False] & /@ 
    Partition[Row /@ (t /. r), k]]]`?

Comment: This does the job.

Answer (score 5):

`Row` formats input list ***"arranged in a row, potentially extending over several lines"***. To prevent line breaks, you can wrap `Row[...]` with `Style` using the option `LineBreakWithin -> False`:

```
ClearAll[fun2]; 
fun2[n_, k_] := With[{t = Tuples[{0, 1}, n], r = {0 -> "\[UpArrow]", 1 -> "\[DownArrow]"}},
  Column[Style[Row[#, " "], LineBreakWithin -> False] & /@ Partition[Row /@ (t /. r), k]]]
```

[image]

Compare with the output from `fun`:

[image]